# How to use Spark to process CSV data and output serialized custom JavaObjects?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a folder with a small CSV file that contains directories: "/catmydata/2017/1/1, /catdata/2017/1/2" that each contain a bunch of CSVs with cat adaptions for each row in the CSV.

I want to using spark distribute the load and convert the data and stick it into binary JavaObject files in an output directory similar to my source data "/convertedcatdata/2017/1/1/adoptedcatjavaobjectbinaryfile, /convertedcatdata/2017/1/1/adoptedcatjavaobjectbinaryfile"

My Java Object that I would use is this:

```
public class Cat{
    private Date dateOfAdoption;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isMale;
    private Person owner;

    public Cat(String name, Boolean isMale, Person owner, Date dateOfAdoption){
       this.name = name;
       this.isMale = isMale;
       this.owner = owner;
       this.dateOfAdoption = dateOfAdoption;
    }
}

public class AdoptedCats{
    public List<Cat> catList;

    public AdoptedCats(){
    }
}
```

I am used to using python spark to convert csv files to avro, but the problem is my output file in this case is a Java object class that is filled in. How can I make it so that I can create such a file where its a serialized java object that contains the AdoptedClass object that is populated with all the cats that are listed in the CSV?

What I mean by this is if someone wrote Java code (non-spark) and opened up the serialized "adoptedcatjavaobjectbinaryfile", they could access the contents of the Java class. Say:

```
AdoptedCats adoptedCats = <the adoptedcatjavaobjectbinaryfile>
System.out.println(adoptedCats.cats.length) // this would output say, 75 if there were 75 rows in the original CSV.
```

I assume I have to use the Java Spark... but am not sure how I can create the spark script so that it can divide and conquer all the cat directories for the whole month of january and get them outputted into their respective directories. Any help or examples would be most helpful.

Comment: Let me explain my understanding before trying to solve it. There is a csv file which contains `N` number of directories path string and each directory has many CSV files. Each CSV has 4 columns `dateOfAdoption, name,isMale,owner ` for which you want to create java object then save. is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's simpler than that. There are N number of directories (path string was typed out as a sample), and each directory has many CSV files. Each csv has those fields you mention that i want to create java object then save the java object on disk. I know how to write csv files, to databases, to avro, etc. but not to Java binary objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to achieve this-

1. Let's say file (I have a folder with a small CSV file that contains directories) is `/somepath/catmydata.csv`

   ```
       JavaSparkContext context  = ......;

       //Retrieve list of files from master file

       List<String> files = context.textFile("/somepath/catmydata.csv")
               .flatMap(row->Arrays.asList(row.split(",")).iterator()).collect();

      //Iterate through each file and save it as object file
      Map<String,JavaRDD<Cat>> adoptedCatsMap =new HashMap<String,JavaRDD<Cat>>();
       for (String file:files) {

          // Extract file path and attach to convert
           String output=String.format("/convertedcatdata/%s",file.substring(file.indexOf('/'),file.length()))

          JavaRDD<Cat> adoptedCatsRdd = context.textFile(file).map(s->new Cat(s));

          adoptedCatsMap.put(output,adoptedCatsRdd);
          //This will write number of files based on rdd partitions,
          // if you want only one file in a directory then save it 
          // to temporary directory then use copyMerge to create one file using Hadoop fs FileUtil
          // https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html
         //Save to physical location if required.
          adoptedCatsRdd.saveAsObjectFile(output);
       }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Given the example I gave used AdoptedCcats as the primary class, that contained a "nested" list of Cat objects (that represent each row in the input csv's) is it still supported in Spark?

Comment: If you happen to bring adoptedCats to driver and adoptedcats size is huge then there are chances your driver run outOfMemory.

Comment: In example `JavaRDD<Cat> adoptedCatsRdd = context.textFile(file).map(s->new Cat(s))`  is equivalent to nested list of Adoptedcats. Instead of saving adoptedCatsRdd you can maintain in another datastructure and this implementation would not have any memory issues.

Comment: @Rolando did it help?